# Formatting HTML buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three likert scales similar to:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
<a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Fearsome</a>
     <button id="fear1" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
     <button id="fear2" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
     <button id="fear3" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
     <button id="fear4" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
     <button id="fear5" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
<a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Fearsome</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/xbytemt/pen/eZjrOG)**

However would like the first button of each scale to be placed exactly under each other for them to be uniform.

Any simple solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a `min-width` to your `a`

```css
.btn-link {
  min-width: 130px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Fearsome</a>
    <button id="fear1" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
    <button id="fear2" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
    <button id="fear3" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
    <button id="fear4" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
    <button id="fear5" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Fearsome</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Controllable</a>
    <button id="control1" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
    <button id="control2" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
    <button id="control3" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
    <button id="control4" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
    <button id="control5" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Totally Controllable</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Dangerous</a>
    <button id="danger1" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
    <button id="danger2" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
    <button id="danger3" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
    <button id="danger4" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
    <button id="danger5" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Dangerous</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer is to put a width styling on  the link using 300px in the following example:

```
<a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled style="width:300px">Not Fearsome</a>
```

This would force all the leading statements to be the same width. I would suggest adding a class and doing via the CSS:

```
//css
.leftSide{width:300px}

<a class="leftSide btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Fearsome</a>
```

you could also pull the links out of the button-group and have them to each side in their own divs:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
<div class="col-md-2">
   <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Not Fearsome</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">

     <button id="fear1" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-1">1</button>
     <button id="fear2" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-2">2</button>
     <button id="fear3" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-3">3</button>
     <button id="fear4" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-4">4</button>
     <button id="fear5" type="button" class="btn btn-default likert-5">5</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <a class="btn btn-link disabled" disabled>Extremely Fearsome</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't advise OP to use inline styles, that's a bad practice

Comment: @dippas - actually - i said that i would recommend using the CSS and adding a class. but fair point!

Comment: still OP is using bootstrap, so no need (in this case) to create more classes :)

Comment: @dippas - correct - unless there are other .btn-link elements ibn the rest of the code that are not required to follow this rule. Te problem with your approach is that ALL .btn-link's through the page will be affected. The benefit of adding a specific class to these elements is to ensure specificity to the targetted elements.

Comment: then just need to be more specific on the rule, not an issue.

Comment: @dippas - gee I wouldn't have through of that...:)

Answer (score 1):

Even though @dippas commented that the class wasn't needed and was the accepted answer, the fact is that **his solution is increasing the width of the last `<a>` of each line unnecessarily**.

A simple and clean way to achieve what you want is using:

```
.btn-link:first-child {
    display:inline-block; 
    width: 150px;
}
```

That way, of the `<a>` with the class `btn-link`, you will only select the first that appears inside the `<div class="btn-group">`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add display property to change the width of the a tag.

```
.btn-link {
    display: inline-block;   
    min-width: 110px;
}
```

Comment: OP is using bootstrap, don't need to overuse  properties